# Cordova Onsen Ui Error with exit code 2

Tags: android, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm getting an error below when running the **cordova emulate** command in my project folder.

```
C:\Android\projects\gcsai>cordova emulate
```

Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Android\projects\gcsai\platforms\android\cordova
\run.bat --emulator""
ERROR: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

**My paths are:**

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\db\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\AndroidSDK\sdk\tools\android.bat;

**My OS is Win Xp Pro SP3**

**Cordova version 5.4.1**

I have checked and the version is set in my **AndroidManifest.xml** (android:versionCode="1") which is one suggested cause of the issue I have read about online.

I have a sample template in the project directory downloaded from the Onsen Ui site and have successfully run the command **cordova platform add android**

It looks to me like something is mis-configured in the project folder?

**Additional info:**

C:\Android\projects\gcsai>cordova run android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Android\projects\gcsai\platforms\android\cordova
\run.bat""
ERROR: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
 code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Help is appreciated its my first project with this framework.

Jimmy

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the project folder, specially if you downloaded the template from this page: http://onsen.io/download.html#download-templates In any case, just create a blank Cordova app, copy paste www folder and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Fran Dios Created a new project from command line **cordova create my-app** then in the new **my-app** directory **cordova platform add android** then switched the www folder and ran **cordova emulate** ... same error I'm afraid. J

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with Onsen UI. It's likely to be a issue related with Cordova running on Windows. It says `Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Android\projects\gcsai\platforms\android\cordova \run.bat""` but the quotation is incorrect in that command. It should use single quotation for the path since double quotes are already in use.

Comment: Hi Fran, yea spotted that myself and thanks for your input. I have given up trying to run the development environment on my ageing system. I am trying to learn now using the **Monaca online IDE** until I upgrade to a newer pc with a more up to date environment.